# Can I reference YouTrack issues on github?

Tags: github, intellij-idea, youtrack

I've integrated YouTrack with GitHub, I have hook set up on git hub, I can run commands on youtrack from git commit messages. I've also integrated IntelliJ with GitHub, so I see issues' ids as YouTrack links like this:
[image: IntelliJ - YouTrack integration]

I wonder, can I configure something similar on GitHub? Can it create links from my issues' ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. This is something GitHub would have to implement themselves and isn't available as an API method.